# NVD3 tooltip pointer not updating position after updating chart data

Tags: tooltip, nvd3.js

I'm using the NVD3 library to draw a graph. I am using the interactive guideline and for some reason after I update the chart data + graph, the tooltip pointers stay at the old position.

[image: tooltip pointer at wrong position]

When I update the data I do this:

> chartData.datum(data).call(chart);

Everything updates fine except the position of the pointers of the tooltip. They seem to get stuck at the old position. I also tried calling this:

> chart.update();

I noticed that when resizing my window and calling chart.update(), the pointers are set to the right position.

Someone any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it! I apparently had to add transition().duration(500);

So in order to update the graph I call this:

> chartData.datum(data)
>                   .transition().duration(500)
>                   .call(chart);

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a Little More description about the problem ... Becuase Previously i was having the Same .. that override the nvd3 tooltip function

`this._nvctp = nv.tooltip.calcTooltipPosition; 
 nv.tooltip.calcTooltipPosition = this.calcTooltipPosition;

```
calcTooltipPosition : function() {
this.findTotalOffsetTop = function(a, b) {
                return 0;
            };
this.findTotalOffsetLeft = function(a, b) {
                return 0;
            };
arguments[0] = [ window.event.pageX, window.event.pageY ];
var p = nvk.tooltip._nvctp.apply(this, arguments);

            p.style.left = (window.event.clientX - (p.clientWidth / 2))
                    + 'px';
            p.style.top = (window.event.clientY - (p.clientHeight * 1.2))
                    + 'px';
            p.style.opacity = 1;
            p.style.position = 'fixed';
            return p;
        }
```